# A question on transformation of probability vectors with stochastic matrices

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, $q=(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ be probability distributions, $p\ne q$.  For which pairs of $p$ and $q$ there exists a stochastic matrix $H$ (i.e. matrix with non negative entries and the sum of elements in every column is equal to 1) s.t. $q=Hp$, $p=Hq$?

The only observation I have is that such a stochastic matrix $H$ is not primitive since $H^2$ has two stationary states $p$ and $q$.

Comment: bi-partite graphs/chains are the natural answer here

Comment: @user8675309 sorry,  i don't understand. Does that mean that it holds only for q being permutations of order 2 of p?

Comment: no. It does not imply permutations.  Can you solve for $p$ and $q$ with $H^T:= \displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, thank you. If you will write it as an answer I'll accept it.